# What is the general formula for tertiary alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

According to my book, the general formula is $\ce{R-OH}$.

But according to the internet, it is $\ce{R3COH}$.

Are both the general formulas correct?

Comment: First, please use the proper term: *tertiary alcohol*. "3°" is a shorthand notation, fine for taking your own notes, but not appropriate in formal writing. Then, look up the definition of a tertiary alcohol, and you can figure out which one is correct from that. If your book really said that it's ROH, I strongly suggest dumping it and getting a new book.

Comment: I agree. You need a better textbook. The internet definition is much more accurate.

Comment: The formula $\pu{R-OH}$ could be used for all sorts of alcohols, and even for other substances like phenols.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to say dump the book. Whether the formula was used correctly depends on the context. For example, "Consider the following reaction involving ROH (a tertiary alcohol) and..."

Comment: The formulae are not inconsistent. "R" can represent anything including "R3C" so the second formula is merely a more specific subset of the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tertiary ($\mathrm{3^\circ}$) alcohol is compound in which the hydroxy group ($\ce{-OH}$) is attached to a tertiary carbon; which again indicates a saturated carbon that is attached to three carbons.

So, the general structure would be (stereochemistry not shown, only connectivity):

[image: tertiary alcohol]

Your confusion arises from the fact that in organic chemistry, the symbol $\ce{R}$ can be used to represent any carbon chain, and so the precise meaning depends on the context.

The most general formula for tertiary alcohol should be $\ce{R^1R^2R^3COH}$, as shown in the picture, to indicate that all three carbon chains can be different. However, $\ce{R3COH}$ is a reasonable way to represent it, as long as you keep in mind the caveat.

$\ce{R-OH}$ is probably not the best way to represent a tertiary alcohol, because it hides the tertiary nature, but it might be acceptable to draw in a reaction scheme in case there was no change in the carbon chain, so it is okay to hide that complexity.

At any rate, it is better to know what it means, than rely on a specific formula, because representations in chemistry are flexible, and can change depending on context.